# Why my react code works on jsfiddle but not on local server

Tags: reactjs

This code works on jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/2gkzqw0o/2/

whereas I get a blank screen on my local server, why ?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">


    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  ?
      <title>test</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
      <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png" />

      <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script> 
      <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="app"></div>
    </body>



  </html>
```

app.js

```
  const title = React.createElement('h1', {}, 'Hi');


  ReactDOM.render(title, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

Comment: do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: What's inside your `app.js` file? My guess is whatever is in it interferes with the render and the reason it works in JSfiddle is cuz it cannot find that app.js file.